# Pin Re-Verification

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm still at the beginner stage of learning Java and I'm currently having a problem in trying to re-enter the PIN code that I first entered to ensure that I entered it correct the second time. It's like setting up a passcode for your mobile device when I open it.
Here's where the problem happens:

```
int firstSet, secondSet;
firstSet = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
jTextField2.setText("");
jLabel1.setText("Re-Enter PIN");
secondSet = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
if(firstSet==secondSet)
{
    jLabel1.setText("PIN VERIFIED");
}
else
{
    jLabel1.setText("PIN INCORRECT");
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

I hope that someone can help me. :)

Comment: You're trying to parse "" as an Integer. Don't do that.

Comment: This is actually how I'm supposed to run the program: 1) I first enter my set of pin, then screen clears. 2) Then I get prompted to re-enter it, 3) if correctly entered, then I get prompted "CORRECT", if wrong then "WRONG" is what I get. This is only taking place in one Textfield. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the problem here

```
jTextField2.setText("");
// ... 
secondSet = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
```

---

You are setting the value of `jTextField2.text` to `""` and when you try: `secondSet = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());` you're getting an empty `String` from `.getText()`, so method [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) is complaining with [`NumberFormatException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html)

As pointed in the [`Integer:parseInt(String) API`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

> Throws:
>   `NumberFormatException` - if the string does not contain a parsable integer.

All this code is executed without interruption, so if you want to do this in this way with only one method call.

First delete this line:

```
jTextField2.setText("");
```

And use 2 text fields.

```
firstSet =  Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
secondSet = Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText());
//                                     ^ here!!!!
```

---

**ADD-ON**

In order to avoid similar problems when ueser enter non valid data, or no dagta at all I would recommend you to safe-parse the values of

```
try {
    firstSet = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
    secondSet = Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    jLabel1.setText("PIN NOT VALID; TRY AGAIN!!!");
}
```

**ALTERNATIVE** if you want to use same jTextField and ask user 2 times to repeat the `PIN CODE` you must adapt your method in order to perform 2 actions:

- Ask user for pin + accept
- Method call: convert pin and save it in a class attribute.
- Erase JTextField
- Ask user again for pin + accept
- Method call: if in class attribute you have a pin stored, compare with user input.

**Example**

```
class YourClass {
    int firstSet = 0; // global attribute!

    public void yourListenerMethod() {
        // if firstSet == 0 is first attempt
        if (firstSet == 0) {
            firstSet = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
            jTextField2.setText("");
            jLabel1.setText("Re-Enter PIN");
        //
        // if firstSet != 0 is second attempt so compare
        } else {
            int secondSet = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
            if(firstSet==secondSet)
            {
                jLabel1.setText("PIN VERIFIED");
                // reset the pin if necessary
                firstSet = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                jLabel1.setText("PIN INCORRECT");
                // reset the pin if necessary
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your responses all. :) I think this is the best solution and closest to my dilemma. However, since I'm still new, I couldn't completely comprehend on this part: ALTERNATIVE if you want to use same jTextField and ask user 2 times to repeat the PIN CODE you must adapt your method in order to perform 2 actions:

    Ask user for pin + accept
    Method call: convert pin and save it in a class attribute.
    Erase JTextField
    Ask user again for pin + accept
    Method call: if in class attribute you have a pin stored, compare with user input. - Can you please tell me more?:)

Comment: By the way, I'm using jframe via netbeans with this program. where I only have 1 textfield 3 button numbers and 1 button confirmation that you will need to press again after re entering the pin code. :)

Comment: Wow it worked! Thank you so much Jordi! You're a genius! :) This is something that my mind can't figure out on my own yet. But I know that someday I will. Thanks again. ;)

Comment: Glad to help!! To understand it, Check points I wrote before. After note the flow, you must think what program needs. Finally you must understand differences of scopes for local and global variables...

Comment: Also don't forget to mark answer as accepted if  solved your problem. Both will get some reputation ;)

Comment: I did use the global variable before on a calculator, but I forgot to use it on this one. I will take note of my first lesson with you ;). Another question though, Whenever I input the numbers, it doesn't follow how a number should be aligned. Though it is RIGHT aligned, the manner that it follows one another is it overlaps the preceding number. Like when I enter 2 & 1, it should show 21, instead it shows 12. I tried checking the properties to possible fix this, but I'm having a hard time.

Comment: Oh yes. sure. Thanks for reminding me about it. Hahaha... I will mark it now. Thank you once again, Hope you could also help me with my last dilemma on this project. Heheh...